# Git Extensions plugin not showing up in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, installation, add-in

The add-in directory exists and has the required files.  It has been added to the list of locations to search under tools/options.  Git extensions independently runs correctly.  Tool bar is not populated with git icons nor the git menu item.  Add-in Manager doesn't list it.

Anyone have ideas on what I can check to find the cause of it not loading this plugin?  The devenv log file doesn't even seem to reference add-ins so there are no related errors I can see.  Its like its not even trying to load plugins.  This is the professional version of 2010.

Answer (score 0):

On a **Windows7** machine in **Programs and Features** I ran **repair Git Extensions** and it solved the problem. If it does not show in Visual Studio go to **Tools/Add-In Manager** and check Git Extensions.

Comment: I never had any luck with this procedure